# java regex to escape oracle sql special characters

Tags: java, sql, regex

I want to escape all the special character is an sql query. So i created thi regex:

```
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\{ | \\} | \\\\ | \\, | \\& | \\? |"
            + " \\( | \\) | \\[ | \\] | \\- | \\; | \\~ | \\| | \\ $ | "
            + "\\! | \\< | \\> | \\* | \\% | \\_");
Matcher m1=p1.matcher(s);
```

Now I want it to iterate through all the matches and put an '\' character before it. For example if a string is : aa%aa$aa, I want it to be aa\%aa\$aa. How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use back reference `$0` to refer to the value of the matched expression:

```
myString.replaceAll(myPattern, "\\\\$0")
```

For example,

```
System.out.println("abcdef".replaceAll("[a-c]", "\\\\$0"));
```

produces

```
\a\b\cdef
```

Note the excessive number of slashes in the replacement: I need to pass two backslashes to regexp (the first one escapes the second one), and for each one I must put two in order for the Java to do its own escaping, for the final count of four.

Answer (score 3):

If all you want to do is escape SQL characters I would recommend using `PreparedStatements` in Java rather than trying to construct your own escaper.

That being said, it would be possible to do so with regex but it wouldn't be easy

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the pattern with parenthesis like so

```
(a)(b)(c)
```

And letter you can refer to them by a $+the ordinal of the parentheses pair

For example, if you apply the replacement pattern

```
$1\$2$3
```

it will give

```
a\bca\bc
```

In java this become

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("(a)(b)(c)", "$1\\\\$2$3");
```